# How do I change/set mysqladmin pw from command-line in Win 7?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, mysqladministrator, mysqladmin

I tried to do:

```
mysqladmin -u root password <password>
```

But I got the following error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed.
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

What could be causing this?

This is a new install of MySQL and I have never configured MySQLadmin, or as far as I know I have never done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows

Comment: Mark your question as answered if you no longer need responses to your question.

Comment: I would, but it won't allow me to for another day. When I posted this answer, it said I needed to wait 2 days.